Пропал favicon сайта в поиске Google. Что делать?
Заметил у моего сайта Kinotv.co не отображается favicon в поисках Google. Ждал в работе алгоритмах поисковика что скоро будут порядок как прежде, но спустя уже неделю нет никаких успешной изменений. По анализу всё в порядке. Выдумал только один вариант: прописать allow в robots.txt отдельно для путей favicon. Что ещё вы можете предложить?


Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Спасибо, исправил.✓

Логичный вопрос — а откуда гугл в принципе должен взять favicon?

Наверное проблема в том что favicon в формате svg. Изменил на ico, посмотрим результаты.
